# Is it possible to add a EventListener to Legends of an AMChart

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I have a polar scatter chart and I have a legend for the same and if you know on clicking on one of the legend items, the points related to the item gets hidden in the chart. So what I am trying to do is on the click event I want call a webmethod from my code. The following is the code I am using

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "DataPolarScatter.aspx/GetDescription",
            data: '{ Code: "' + SelectedCode + '" }',
            success: function (val) {
                var Data = $.parseJSON(val.d);

                var xaxis = 0;
                var yaxis = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
                    chartFilterDataSymp.push({ "Code": Data[i].Code, "Name": Data[i].Name, "Count": Data[i].Count });
                    grphArr.push({ "Code": Data[i].Code, "title": Data[i].Code + "[" + Data[i].Name + "]" + ", Count: " + Data[i].Count, "balloonText": Data[i].Code + "[" + Data[i].Name + "]" + ", Count: " + Data[i].Count, "bullet": "round", "lineAlpha": 0, "series": [[xaxis, yaxis]] });
                    xaxis = xaxis + 100;
                    yaxis = yaxis + 4;
                }

                var chartdivRadar = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivRadar", {
                    type: "radar",
                    dataProvider: chartFilterDataSymp,
                    categoryField: "Name",
                    startDuration: 2,

                    valueAxes: [{
                        axisAlpha: 0.15,
                        minimum: 0,
                        dashLength: 3,
                        axisTitleOffset: 20,
                        gridCount: 5,
                        radarCategoriesEnabled: false
                    }],


                    graphs: [{
                        valueField: "Count",
                        bullet: "round",
                        balloonText: "[[category]]: [[value]]"
                    }],
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "libs": {
                            "autoLoad": false
                        }
                    }
                });
                //var legendRadar = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                //chartdivRadar.addLegend(legendRadar, "legendRadar");

                //// WRITE
                //chartdivRadar.write("chartdivRadar");

                chartdvPolarSctr = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivPolarScatter", {
                    type: "radar",//   theme: "light",
                    dataProvider: chartFilterDataSymp,
                    startDuration: 1,

                    valueAxes: [{
                        "axisAlpha": 0.15,
                        "dashLength": 3,
                        "axisTitleOffset": 20,
                        "gridCount": 5,
                        "gridType": "circles",
                        "minimum": 0
                    }],

                    polarScatter: {
                        "minimum": 0,
                        "maximum": 5000,
                        "step": 1
                    },

                    graphs: grphArr
                });

                chartdvPolarSctr.addListener("clickGraphItem", function (event) {
                   // debugger;
                    //alert(event.item.dataContext);
                    //alert(event.item.values.value);
                    //alert(event.item.category);
                    var url = "TopTenCharts.aspx?Code=" + "78321";
                    window.location.href = url;
                });

                var legendPolarScatter = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                legendPolarScatter.addListener("clickLegendItem", function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DataPolarScatter.aspx/AddRemoveCode",
                        data: event.item.category,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert('Code removed');
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    });
                });
                chartdvPolarSctr.addLegend(legendPolarScatter, "legendPolarScatter");

                // WRITE
                chartdvPolarSctr.write("chartdivPolarScatter");
            }
        });
```

So is it possible to add a listener to the legends and if yes what would be the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using the wrong event and hence my code wasn't working. Since I needed the action when I was hiding a Item I used the hideItem event

Here's a link to the list of events available for legends: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend

```
   legendPolarScatter.addListener("hideItem", function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DataPolarScatter.aspx/AddRemoveCode",
                        data: '{ Code: "' + event.dataItem.title + '" }',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            //alert('Code removed');
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            //alert(e.error);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Just an FYI - don't call write to redraw/update the chart after adding your legend and other stuff. Use [`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) or [`validateNow()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateNow) instead.